# Restore Unix Tapes in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, backup, tape

Hi Guys,
I have some tape Cartridges written in UNIX/ Linux which i want to restore in a Windows Vista/ 2003 64bit Server system. Can anyone suggest the software/ tools required. Windows doesn't recognize these tapes when i insert in Tape Drive.

Good Luck,
Pinaki

Comment: Did you really mean to tag this Question with the Python tag?

Comment: what sofware was used to make the backups?

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully used Cygwin dd to read and write tapes under Windows - perhaps that will work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered booting your system with a Knoppix or other Linux LiveCD that contains some of those Unix tape utilities to read the data off the tape and dump it to your hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Zoredache, it depends a great deal on what you used to write the data.

If you used tar (or amanda, which uses freely available tools), Richie's suggestion of using cygwin may be good, because you may be able to get whatever tool running under it.

I don't think that 'dd' will give you much usable information, since it will essentially create tape images. The exception would be if you were to make images of the tapes and present them to a Linux virtual machine running whatever software you used to create them.

More information will get you a better answer.